# Android App Incompatibility with Nexus 7

Tags: android, camera, tablet, google-play, nexus-7

The play store is showing that my app is not compatible with the Nexus 7 (older model with only front-facing camera, ME370T).  My app does require a camera but can use the front-facing camera.  I tried to take this into account in my Manifest by specifying that *any* camera could be used (not just the back facing camera):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
```

Otherwise, I have no idea why it's not able to run on the Nexus 7.  Here are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Any ideas why I can't install the app?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the app store may ignore the "any" specification for uses-feature.  I changed my camera requirement to

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

and it seems like it's supported now.

Comment: Interesting to know for future reference.