# Nexus 7 - app does not appear in store

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, nexus-7

I've published my app to the Google Play store, and for some reason, I do not see my app appearing when browsing the store with the Nexus 7 device.

Here's the relevant section in my manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" >
    </uses-feature>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="20">
    </uses-sdk>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" >
    </uses-permission>


    <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" 
        android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="720"/>
```

I've already looked at several posts in stack overflow:

- [Nexus 7 compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267986/nexus-7-compatibility-issue)
- [My App isn't Compatible with Nexus 7 on Google Playstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263138/my-app-isnt-compatible-with-nexus-7-on-google-playstore)
- [Android App Incompatibility with Nexus 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234098/android-app-incompatibility-with-nexus-7)
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing

But none of these posts seem to be relevant to my situation. I don't seem to be requiring anything from the device in my app which the Nexus 7 device doesn't support.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<supports-screens
   android:smallScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true"
   android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Yep, this is correct, but the underlining issue is that the android:requiresSmallestWidthDp & android:compatibleWidthLimitDp *should* work and replace these attributes. I'll up-vote you, but the correct answer was my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem.

Apparently, the android:requiresSmallestWidthDp & android:compatibleWidthLimitDp attributes are not supported on every device, and that it is still required to add the large & xlarge attributes in the support-screens tag. Google are intending to roll-out the large/xlarge/etc attributes and rely solely on the compatible/required width DP attribute, but for now, it's still necessary to set these attributes.